# A Cloudformation managed service is being restarted regularly and the application logs are getting cleaned out

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a *node.js* application launched by _CloudFormation that is being restarted frequently.  I am wondering why:

- is it generating *stderr* - and then maybe *CloudWatch* cycles it?

In addition the application logs are being cycled and the old logs are not being retained.

- How can the logs be retained?

Note: the archived *access* logs are available in Cloudwatch that stores them to S3. I am uncertain how to enable and find the archived *application* logs representing the *stout* and *stderr* from our service.

Here is the *LogConfiguration* setting in the *service-myServiceName-server.yml* :

```
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Sub /ECS-CLUSTER/${AWS::Region}/${TypeProject}
              awslogs-stream-prefix: /ecs-task-output
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
```

*Update*  @tianz encouraged me to spend more quality time looking through CloudWatch logs: and yes they do appear there.

```
 CloudWatch/CloudWatch Logs/Log groups/ /ECS-CLUSTER/us-east-2/prod
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have LogConfiguration in your TaskDefinition? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-logconfiguration.html

Comment: @tianz  Yes it appears so: updated the question.  I did not set this up and am a newbie to CF/CW/ECS .

Comment: And do you mean there is only access logs in `/ECS-CLUSTER/${AWS::Region}/${TypeProject}` but not application logs?

Comment: I'll look around a bit more on S3 to see what I can find

Comment: There is nothing in CloudWatch itself?

Comment: @tianz  Looks like that is the right place. It was not where I first looked . Will update my question. Please make it an answer using the path I put into the question at the bottom

Comment: Awesome! I made it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `LogConfiguration` you should be able to locate your logs in CloudWatch under the log group `/ECS-CLUSTER/${AWS::Region}/${TypeProject}`